# GraphQL print function doesn't escape string correctly

Tags: javascript, axios, graphql

I am using the following code:

```
const GQL_ADD_JOB = gql`
    mutation AddJob {
        addJob(title: $title, company: $company, description: $description) {
            title
            company
            description
        }
    }
    `;
```

And then using axios, I attempt to POST using GraphQL's `print` function:

```
request.post(
  GQL_ENDPOINT,
  {
    query: print(GQL_ADD_JOB),
    variables: {
      title: job.title,
      company: job.company,
      description: job.description,
    },
  }
)
```

Where `job.title`, `job.company`, and `job.description` can all be strings containing any character, including newlines, quotes, etc. However, calling this results in a JSON parse error. The error shows that the request sent the following data:

> '{"query":"mutation AddJob {\n  addJob(title: $title, company: $company, description: $description) {\n    title\n    company\n    description\n  }\n}","variables":{"title":"Route Service Sales Representative - 3rd Shift","company":"Cintas","description":"test desc"}}'

When I use this data and manually perform a POST via curl, I get the following error:

> {"message":"Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character "\\".","extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED","exception":{"stacktrace":["GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character "\\".","    at syntaxError (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:15:10)","    at readToken (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/lexer.js:360:40)","    at Lexer.lookahead (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/lexer.js:75:108)","    at Lexer.advance (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/lexer.js:58:35)","    at Parser.expectToken (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1408:19)","    at Parser.many (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1519:10)","    at Parser.parseSelectionSet (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:271:24)","    at Parser.parseOperationDefinition (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:199:26)","    at Parser.parseDefinition (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:137:23)","    at Parser.many (/home/user/repos/comp/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1523:26)"]}}}

Comment: So the problem is not the `request.post` call, it's the backend that doesn't like this request? Do you own the api, can you share its code or debug on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my mutation to this and now it works. I still don't fully understand why the other format didn't work.

```
mutation AddJob($title: String!, $company: String!, $description: String!) 
{
    addJob(title: $title, company: $company, description: $description)
}
```

Comment: Your mutation is missing the variables declaration, but indeed that should have caused a validation error not a parse error. Especially since there's no `.` in the request…

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).